# Java program does not connect to internet?

Tags: java, network-programming

This program compiles successfully but when I try to run the program it gives me errors.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   throws Exception {
      URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
      (new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
      BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter
      (new FileWriter("data.html"));
      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
         writer.write(line);
         writer.newLine();
      }
      reader.close();
      writer.close();
   }
}
```

The following error occurs (I have attached the image):

[Screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6kif.png)

*I am behind a **proxy server**. Does that make a problem in connecting to the internet? If so please post the solution that .. Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Please post the **text** of the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something similar:

1st of all put proxy information to system properties:

```
System.getProperties().put( "proxySet", "true" );
System.getProperties().put( "proxyHost", "proxy_hostname" );
System.getProperties().put( "proxyPort", "8080" ); // or other proxy port
```

And then you need to do authentication on proxy, using something similar:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
String pass = "MY_USERNAME:MY_PASS";
String encodedPass = base64Encode( pass );
con.setRequestProperty( "Proxy-Authorization", encodedPass );
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Proxy settings can protect a standalone app from connecting to internet. If you know the proxy try using

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=yourProxy & -Dhttp.proxyPort=proxyPort
```

These are VM arguments. If you are running it command line then use it as

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=yourProxy & -Dhttp.proxyPort=proxyPort Main
```

Comment: Let the person know where to use this line

Comment: Where should I use this? Should I type this in Command Prompt?

Comment: Yes, if you are running via commandline. If you want to run it via Eclipse, go to Run configurations and set this as VM arguments